# 'void' type not allowed here - listener to a parameter

Tags: java, swing, events, panel, jtextfield

Why you can't add a listener to a object which is a parameter?

```
panelThird.add(new JTextField( "Write here !" ).addActionListener(
        new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                dlm.addElement(e.getActionCommand());
            }
        }), 
        BorderLayout.SOUTH);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`addActionListener` has a return type of void - so you can't write:

```
panelThird.add(new JTextField(...).addActionListener(...));
```

Instead, you need:

```
JTextField field = new JTextField(...);
field.addActionListener(...);
panelThird.add(field);
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are adding the listener to the textfield, the return value is void, and you can't add void to the panelThird.

```
JTextField tf = new JTextField( "Write here !" );
tf.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
       public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) { 
             dlm.addElement(e.getActionCommand());
       }
})  
panelThird.add(tf, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
```